# Matplotlib installation error [Python 3.10]

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, installation

I need to use matplotlib for plotting some parametric curves for college. I tried installing it on my windows machine but the following error shows up everytime I execute

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

[image]

Comment: The error message literally says that NumPy may not support Python 3.10 yet.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks, I am new to all this kinda stuff, never used python before, I was just following the steps on the webpage

Comment: python 3.10 is too new.  Not all packages, including `numpy` have been updated to work with it.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Answer (score 0):

For the windows machine, I could not find any precompiled wheel for your python version 3.10. But found unofficial wheels here, [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Depending on your architecture version, you can download either one.

- numpy‑1.21.2+mkl‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl or
- numpy‑1.21.2+mkl‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl

Then download the suitable one and go to the download directory and run

> pip install numpy‑1.21.2+mkl‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl

if you have x64 architecture or run

> pip install numpy‑1.21.2+mkl‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl

If you have x86 architecture.
This process worked for me. Give it a try.